# Deconstructing gulp object in gulpfile but getting errors:

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to deconstruct gulp instance, but getting errors when I do. Here's my working gulpfile:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
...
// Task for compiling sass. Run with 'gulp sass'
gulp.task('sass', () => gulp.src(SASS_SRC)
  ...
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css')));
```

Here's the changes I've made to try to make the code a little cleaner:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
...
const {
  task,
  src,
  dest,
} = gulp; // <-- added this
// Task for compiling sass. Run with 'gulp sass'
task('sass', () => src(SASS_SRC)
  ...
  .pipe(dest('./dist/css')));
```

But I'm getting errors when I run `gulp`:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'tasks' of undefined
> at Orchestrator.add (C:\Users\marty\Sites\nmis\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:54:8)
> at Object. (C:\Users\marty\Sites\nmis\gulpfile.js:51:1)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
> at requireOrImport (C:\Users\marty\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\shared\require-or-import.js:19:11)

I can't understand why this would even be an issue as I'm just referrencing the 'task' property of the gulp object. Why is `task(..)` here any different to simply calling `gulp.task(..)`?

Comment: Works for me. Check for mismatched braces. Extract minimal reproducible example.